# Classname prop won't update with conditional rendering in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a carousel in react. For some reason, the ${fadeIn ? styles.fade_in : ""} line in className for rendering the animation didn't work. Even though I set it to false when calling handelSlider, it still rendered the fade_in animation, resault the carousel automatically move to the third image

My though was using a container to wrap the picture, and put them in a parent div with flex set to 100% so I can conditianly change the position for each photo. Each time after rendering the transition animation, I remove the animation then swap the  current and next piture so it reset for the next animation. However, for some reason, even though when the fadein state set to false, the fadein css prop was still added. So confused, please help
`

```
const Slider = () => {
  const bannerPics = [banner1, banner2, banner3];
  const [fadeIn, setFadeIn] = useState(false);
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState(0);
  const [next, setNext] = useState(1);

  const prevPic = <img src={bannerPics[prev]} alt="" />;
  const nextPic = <img src={bannerPics[next]} alt="" />;

  const handelSlider = () => {
    setFadeIn(!fadeIn);
    setFadeIn(!fadeIn);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(fadeIn);
      if (next === bannerPics.length - 1) setNext(0);
      else {
        setPrev(prev + 1);
        setNext(next + 1);
      }
    }, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.banner}>
        <div
          className={`${styles.pic_container} ${fadeIn ? styles.fade_in : ""}`}
        >
          {prevPic}
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${styles.pic_container} ${fadeIn ? styles.fade_in : ""}`}
        >
          {nextPic}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={handelSlider}>MOVE</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

`

Comment: You are calling setFadeIn(!fadeIn); twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were going for something like this:

```
  const handleSlider = () => {
    if (fadeIn) return;
    setFadeIn(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPrev((i) => (i + 1) % bannerPics.length);
      setNext((i) => (i + 1) % bannerPics.length);
      setFadeIn(false);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

```css
.pic-container {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

It's probably more accurate to call that class / variable just `fade` since it is controlling both fading in and out.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-n6sug4?file=App.tsx

Comment: Thank you, changing setFadeIn(true/false) fixed it. What I don't understand is when I use setFadeIn(!fadeIn) to toggle true and false, even console.log return false, for some reason in the dev tool the classname for that div was still shows the fadein style as if that condition (fadeIn ? styles.fade_in:'') return true.

Comment: `setFadeIn(!fadeIn)` is not the same as `fadeIn = !fadeIn`. State variables are supposed to be immutable, they will not change during a render. On the next render, it will be a new variable, and may have a new value. On the first press of the button, you set the value to `true` twice, then the next you set it to `false` twice, etc. When you do `console.log(fadeIn)` you see the current value, not the one you set it to. Move the log outside the function and you will see the new value on the next render. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.